# Got QueryString error when executing query on athena with boto client

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to execute my query using Athena boto client.

```
self.athena_client = boto3.client('athena')

response = self.athena_client.start_query_execution(
                QueryString=sql.format(**query_params) if query_params else sql,
                ResultConfiguration={
                    'OutputLocation': '...'
                }
            )
```

But I'm getting the error bellow:

```
Invalid length for parameter QueryString, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
```

I couldn't figure out what is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You should certify you are correctly sending the `QueryString` param to boto method `start_query_execution`.

It's a required parameter and it'll throw this error when you, for example, request send `QueryString` with an empty string.

> Check more here at [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution)